# Random Positioning Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my Solar System website I am looking to have a large amount of small shining white circles (Maybe 1 or 2px big) dotted in random places on the background each time the website is visited. The circles don't have to be scr="" images, it can just be plain white coloured circles.

```css
html {
  background-color: #000;
}
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgb(204, 153, 0) 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}
.earth {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: green 0 0 25px;
}
.earth-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
  /*border: 1px dotted gray;*/
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}
.moon {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.moon-orbit {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-bottom: -37px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 1s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vanishing Act</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="sun" src="sun_transparent.png">
  </div>
  <div class="earth-orbit">
    <div class='moon-orbit'>
      <img class="moon" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24899062/cc/moon.png" />
    </div>

    <img class="earth" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24899062/cc/earth.png" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And, what's your question? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: My question is how could I do it, I don't want to just individually position each star, I need javascript to do it for me and randomize it too.

Comment: Okay, but where did you get stuck..?

Comment: That is my problem, I have no idea of how I would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of "polluting" the DOM with a large number of object which ultimately can contribute to the page being rendered slower, why not consider a solution using canvas to draw the stars into?

This will be a single, but larger, DOM element but can be redrawn very fast and you have some artistic freedom as well if needed:

```js
// load images (just one in this example)
sun = new Image();
sun.onload = function() {
  renderStars(750, 0.5, 1.5);
}
sun.src = "http://www.mprgroup.net/images/august2011/sun_transparent.png";

function renderStars(count, minSize, maxSize) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),

    i = 0,
    x, y, size;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (; i < count; i++) {
    x = canvas.width * Math.random();
    y = canvas.height * Math.random();
    size = minSize + (maxSize - minSize) * Math.random();

    // draw circle
    ctx.moveTo(x + size, y);
    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fill();

  var r = 100; // image "radius"
  ctx.drawImage(sun, (canvas.width - r) * 0.5, (canvas.height - r) * 0.5, r, r);
}

 document.getElementById("refresh").onclick = function() {
  renderStars(750, 0.5, 1.5)
};
```

```css
#canvas {background: #000}
#refresh {position: fixed}
```

```html
<button id="refresh">@</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Finally draw the sun etc. on top of the stars (`drawImage(sun, x, y [,width, height])`);

The canvas needs to redrawn every time its size changes.

To set the canvas to fill the window (assuming you use CSS to place it fixed in the top left corner):

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: I was about to say to OP "use `canvas`!" and than... :) +1

Comment: I would give you another +50 (if I could) if you just atomized a diagonal area with a higher concentration of stars mimicking the Milky-Way :)

Comment: P.S: `sun = new Image;` should be `var sun = new Image();`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah, it's do-able. I can define a numerical gradient so it gets higher concentration in center/diagonal. Oh, the Image/Image() is not a typo actually, but I´ll update as many reacts to it. :)

Comment: ... it'll throw error in any JS debugger since it's a constructor. Also I've found in my experience `canvas.width = canvas.width;` a much performable way of clearing the canvas (although not needed in this exact case.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you *can* use native object this way (wo/the parentheses). The debugger will see the `new` keyword and assume the parentheses wo/checking if the object is native/executes (it´s just syntax/formatting level at that stage). If you execute it you will see the object is created wo/ error and load is triggered (which it wouldn't do if it wasn't properly constructed). It's admittedly a special case though (works for other native objects as well such as Array etc.), I'm not sure why I got stuck with it - I suspect minimizing related at one point :) Also, agreed, I found w = w is faster.

Comment: Optional milkyway: draw in a subtle gradient in the background replacing the clearRect.

Answer (score 5):

That's a nice effect.

You can create a `star` class:

```
.star {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
}
```

To ensure that stars are always behind the solar system objects, apply a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to your solar system images:

```
img {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You can add random stars to the sky by giving them left/top coordinates based on multiplying [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) by the screen's width and height:

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++) {
  var x = Math.random()*screen.width;
  var y = Math.random()*screen.height;
  var star= document.createElement('div');
  star.className= 'star';
  star.style.left= x+'px';
  star.style.top= y+'px';
  document.body.appendChild(star);
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #000;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
}

.star {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
}

.sun {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.earth {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.earth-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
  /*border: 1px dotted gray;*/
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}
.moon {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.moon-orbit {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-bottom: -37px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 1s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="sun" src="http://www.mprgroup.net/images/august2011/sun_transparent.png">  
<div class="earth-orbit">
  <div class='moon-orbit'>
    <img class="moon" src="http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/moon-transparent.png" />
  </div>
  <img class="earth" src="http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/earth-transparent.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, and how do I make it so all the other objects go on top of the star background?

Comment: I gave them a z-index of 1 in my answer but forgot to document that.  If they are given a background, they should hide the stars.

Comment: I've updated my response, and I used actual URLs for the sun, earth, and moon images.